# How to check java compilation error in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

It is very clear to see the compilation error in eclipse, but I found it is not very clear in intellij, do I miss something here ? thanks

Comment: Maybe you're hiding the console.

Comment: Press Alt+0 to show all compilation messages.

Comment: It's not working, I am on mac

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/messages-tool-window.html ? do you have this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To see a list of all files with compilation errors, click Project on
>   the title bar of the Project tool window and, under Scopes, select
>   Problems. The other alternative is to use the Problems tool window
>   (View | Tool Windows | Problems).

From 'IntelliJ IDEA Q&A for Eclipse Users': https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html